# DataTables dropdown filter based on the tr class name

Tags: datatables

Just wandering will it be possible for me to filter the records by the tr class name in DataTables dropdown filter?

Example I have a dropdown as following:

```
                    <div>
                    <select>
                        <option value="Default">All</option>
                        <option value="Unread">Unread</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

and the tr as following:

```
<tr class="unread">
     <td>test1</<td>
</tr>
<tr class="read">
    <td>test2</<td>
</tr>
<tr class="unread">
   <td>test3</<td>
</tr>
```

when the dropdown selected the Unread, it will call the following js code to filter out the tr with "read" class and only show the one with "unread" class name:

```
     $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
            var test = settings.nTable.id;
         }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly there with looking at adding to `search` but you needed a reference to the tables `api` within it. This seems to work:

```
$(function() {
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
            if ($("#selector").val() !== "Default") {
                var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);
                return api.row(dataIndex).nodes().to$().hasClass("unread");
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    );
    var example = $("#example").DataTable();
    $("#selector").on("change", function() {
        example.draw();
    });
});
```

And here's a working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/xyv92L26/), hope that helps.